# Django ModelForm saves and fetches <QuerySet object> instead of values

Tags: django

I have a simple Django 3.1.0 app I need to create in order to assign Tasks with Tags (or assign tags into tasks).

**Model**

```
class Task(models.Model):

    user = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="None", null=True)

class Tag(models.Model):

    tag = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="No Tag")
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Task', related_name="tag")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "tags"
```

**view**

```
def main(request):
    model = Task.objects.values().all()
    tags = Tag.objects.values().all()
    form = TaskForm()
    con = {'context': list(model), 'form': form, 'tags': list(tags)}
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = TaskForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    return render(request, "tasks.html", con)
```

**form**

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['user', 'task', 'tags']
        template_name = 'tasks.html'

    tags = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset= Tag.objects.all(),
    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False,
    )
```

**task_form**

```
<form method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

This returns in the tags list the items listed as:

- Tag object (1)
- Tag object (2)

And when it saves when i press submit, it fetches in a table (in another template), the values saved in the text of `<QuerySet [<Tag: Tag object (2)>]>`
That's how it stores them in the database.

I have managed to extract the values as they are ('jenkins','AKS') and send them in the template using this (bootstrapvuejs) : `{% for tag in tags %}<b-form-checkbox>{{tag.tag}}</b-form-checkbox>{% endfor %}`, which lists them raw values perfectly.

However, when I do that modification, the form submitted is not written to database.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE!**
I have partly solved it by adding this into the Tag model:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

but when it persists it on submit, it still saves it as:
`<QuerySet [<Tag: jenkins>]>`

So, how and where do I strip only the specific tag values to be inserted in the database?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , I solved the POST data that is saved in database as Queryset, by extracting in the view where save() is called, the field 'tags' likewise:

```
          f = form.save(commit=False)
          f.tags = request.POST['tags']
          form.save()
```

The only problem now is that I have multiple checkboxes in the form but this way it extracts only one of them, whilst I would expect it to return a list like what is printed in the `request.POST` : `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['XV7HgTFiWXEnrkhqT3IsqUN2JbnT7YIH5r6fKgh2ehqeLsLMpvCPdUU4N2qwWuPk'], 'user': ['afa'], 'task': ['aff'], 'tags': ['jenkins', 'AKS']}>` -> from that I call 'tags' but it saves only 'jenkins' ...

***UPDATE***
OK, I RTFM and saw that there is a method on the QueryDict object that can be passed to `request.POST.getlist('tags')` , so now it returns the complete value of 'tags' key.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so there is a couple issues with your code, first off your main **view**:

Change it from this:

```
def main(request):
    model = Task.objects.values().all() # calling values without specifying an argument makes no sense so just call it like **Task.objects.all()**
    tags = Tag.objects.values().all() # same here
    form = TaskForm() # don't call your form here it gets reassigned later anyways
    con = {'context': list(model), 'form': form, 'tags': list(tags)} # don't define your context here since you are reasigning your form later so the form instance is always TaskForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = TaskForm()

    return render(request, "tasks.html", con)
```

To this:

```
def main(request):
    model = Task.objects.all()
    tags = Tag.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = TaskForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()

    context = {'tasks': model, 
               'form': form, 
               'tags': tags}

    return render(request, "tasks.html", con)
```

Then in your template pass your form with `as_p` method call:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Hovewer the error you are getting is not because of your **html** or your **view**, it's because your `tags` field in your `Task` model is not a `ManyToMany` relationship to your `Tag` model but rather a simple `CharacterField` and you are trying to save `objects` to the `CharField`, so rewrite your `Task` model like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tags = models.ManyToMany(Tags)
```

Then your form should save them in the `tags` field of your `Task` instance and you can view them like this:

```
task = Task.objects.get(pk=1)
task_tags = task.tags.all() # stores a queryset of all tags of the queried task
```

and in the **template**:

```
{% for tag in task.tags.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hm...when i change the view into what you mentioned, it simply didn't fetch any data in the table from the db...as if 'context' is empty, which i tried to print in the template and it is empty. it only returns QuerySet Objects which i am not sure how to handle there..